# nosetest got invalid syntax error

Tags: python, urllib, nose

I'm using nosetests.
Command is `nosetests .\test.py  --nologcapture`
The test.py is as below:

```
import unittest
import json

from nose.tools import assert_true, assert_raises
import requests

endpoint = u"http://www.bing.com"
try:
    import urllib
    raw_status = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(endpoint).read())
except Exception, e:#line 11
    raise e
```

Error like below:
[image]

My python --version shows me Python2.7 used. While echo PATH under the **same prompt** show only Python35 (I'm also puzzled about this).

Anyone knows why this error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: The correct syntax is `except Exception as e: raise e`

Comment: Even better, *don't* do that. There is absolutely no point catching an exception only to raise it.